# How can i solve the multidefine error in arcgis basemap toggle?

Tags: dojo, arcgis

> I want to use the basemap toggle of arcgis but when i am using this, I
>   am getting the error related "multidefine"
>
> This is my function which is am using for invoking the map service

```
[![function handlerForVariableB (latt, longt, complaintid)
{


  // execute code that is relevant when "$a" was set on the server-side. 
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "tools/nrega_v2.1/map.php",
    data: 'complaintid='+complaintid,
    success: function(data){         
      var data_array = JSON.parse(data);


  $('.modal-info').html("");

  var hrymap='<div id="hrymap"></div>';
    $(".modal-info").append(hrymap);

  $('#hrymap').html(""); 

    $('#hrymap').html("<div id='map' style='width:850px;height:650px;'><div id='BasemapToggle'></div></div>");


      var map;

      define.amd.jQuery = true;  
       require(\[
      "esri/map", 
      "esri/dijit/BasemapToggle",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    \], function(
      Map, BasemapToggle
    )  {

      map = new Map("map", {
        center: \[-70.6508, 43.1452\],
        zoom: 16,
        basemap: "topo"
      });

      var toggle = new BasemapToggle({
        map: map,
        basemap: "satellite"
      }, "BasemapToggle");
      toggle.startup();

    });


     $("#detail_content").css({'display':'block'});



    }
  });



}][1]][1]
```

> Please check the attached image which show confliction.
>   I am using jquery plus dojo in my application

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the div Id is conflicting with the BasemapToggle declaration. Have you tried removing the div? I have BasemapToggle bound to my map without specifying a separate div for it and it works great.

```
// execute code that is relevant when "$a" was set on the server-side. 
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "tools/nrega_v2.1/map.php",
    data: 'complaintid='+complaintid,
    success: function(data){         
      var data_array = JSON.parse(data);


  $('.modal-info').html("");

  var hrymap='<div id="hrymap"></div>';
    $(".modal-info").append(hrymap);

  $('#hrymap').html(""); 

    $('#hrymap').html("<div id='map' style='width:850px;height:650px;'></div>");


      var map;

      define.amd.jQuery = true;  
       require(\[
      "esri/map", 
      "esri/dijit/BasemapToggle",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    \], function(
      Map, BasemapToggle
    )  {

      map = new Map("map", {
        center: \[-70.6508, 43.1452\],
        zoom: 16,
        basemap: "topo"
      });

      var toggle = new BasemapToggle({
        map: map,
        basemap: "satellite"
      });
      toggle.startup();

    });


     $("#detail_content").css({'display':'block'});



    }
  });
```

Comment: Still am facing the same ussye

Comment: Which version are you using? Using 4.12 the BasemapToggle is found under the Widgets sub-folder and "map" must be capitalized. I was able to get past the error doing those two changes.
  require([
   "esri/Map",
   "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
   "dojo/domReady!"